# ios 5 twitter initial log in

Tags: twitter, ios5

Using the twitter api in ios5 how do i go about letting the user sign in initially?
I see how it works using accounts.h if a user has already signed in on the device but is there a way to bring the user to the settings twitter screen to sign in if there is no twitter accounts logged in already?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code if no account on device is added in settings it will transferred to the settings page

```
-(void)postOnTwitter:(id)sender
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [twitter addImage:self.imgView.image];
    [twitter setInitialText:@"Photo From Application on iPhone"];
    [self presentModalViewController:twitter animated:NO];

    twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) 
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    };

}
```

Comment: sorry this doesnt transfer the user to the settings page for me. just the alert

Comment: ok i will update my answer now that will definitely solve your problems

Comment: this will show one action sheet which give option for go to settings and set account for tweeter

Comment: ah cool i see how that works now. but is there anyway to bring them to settings page without having to present the TWTweetComposeViewController at all? I dont want the user to send a tweet at this point at all i just want them to sign into app through their twitter account so i can reverse auth it to sign in with my server.

Answer (score 0):

or you can go to setting page by`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];` in iOS 5.0 (**but it should not worked in iOS 5.1)**

for that

It is little tricky , i get by the removing the subviews  in `*TWTWeetComposeViewController*`, so it shows only alert when user is not loged in and by the clicking on setting button , we can open Setting page in my app.

```
 + (void)setAlertForSettingPage :(id)delegate 
{
 // Set up the built-in twitter composition view controller.
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];


    // Create the completion handler block.
    [tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        [delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];

    // Present the tweet composition view controller modally.
    [delegate presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
    //tweetViewController.view.hidden = YES;
    for (UIView *view in tweetViewController.view.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

}

here , deleate is your viewcontroller , if you are using this method inside your viewcontroller just use `self` instead of `delegate`.

Comment: This does not work in the simulator, the settings button when pressed has the same effect as cancel.